# Django: Send mail to admin on every error raised

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I have a project where we process data from various sources. My problem is I want a to send email every time there is an error or error raise my me.

Currently I do something like this where on every raise I send a email. But I want a system where on every error there would be a email sent.

```
# send an email alert
email_content = "Email content"
subject = "Subject"
if settings.ENVIRONMENT == 'PROD':
    BaseScraper.email_alert_for_error(
       subject,
       email_content,
       ["admin@mail.com"],
       )
else:
    BaseScraper.email_alert_for_error(
       subject,
       email_content,
       ["admin@mail.com"],
       )
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `try:` and `except:` like such:

```
 try:
     <do something>
 except Exception as e:
      email_content = email_content + e
      BaseScraper.email_alert_for_error(
           subject,
           email_content,
           ["admin@mail.com"],
      )
```

Here a list of keyword for exception: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/exceptions/

Comment: I would advise adding `raise` at the bottom to re-raise the exception, otherwise you might alter the code flow.